# How to change the Linux display user name on the prompt

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

Choose Menu System->Administration->Users and Groups

I am able to see my Users Settings as follows:

User name: mike

Then why I still see the following prompt line?

```
user@ubuntu:~$ echo $USER
user
user@ubuntu:~$
```

I expect to see the following

```
mike@ubuntu:~$ echo $USER
mike
mike@ubuntu:~$
```

If my understanding is wrong, then how can I change it in this way?

Comment: Did you logout and login again?

Comment: @larsmans, yes, I did. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think the name `mike` is stored in Gnome, and not visible in the whole system.

Your real system name is `user`. Take a look at [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-rename-user-name-id/) to change your username.